# SED or AWK script to replace multiple text

Tags: python, perl, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to do the following with a sed script but it's taking too much time. Looks like something I'm doing wrongly.

Scenario:
I've student records (> 1 million) in `students.txt`.
In This file (each line) 1st 10 characters are student ID and next 10 characters are contact number and so on

**students.txt**

> 1000000001**9234567890**XXX... 
>   1000000002**9325788532**YYY... 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   1001000000**8766443367**ZZZZ...

I have another file (encrypted_contact_numbers.txt) which has all the phone but numbers and corresponding encrypted phone numbers as below

**encrypted_contact_numbers.txt**

> **Phone_Number, Encrypted_Phone_Number** 
>   9234567890, 1122334455 
>   9325788532, 4466742178 
>   .
>   . 
>   .
>   8766443367, 2964267747

I wanted to replace all the contact numbers (11th–20th position) in `students.txt` with the corresponding encrypted phone number from `encrypted_contact_numbers.txt`.

**Expected Output:**

> 1000000001**1122334455**XXX... 
>   1000000002**4466742178**YYY... 
>   . 
>   . 
>   . 
>   1001000000**2964267747**ZZZZ...

I am using the below sed script to do this operation. It is working fine but too slowly.

**Approach 1:**

```
while read -r pattern replacement; do   
    sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/" students.txt
done < encrypted_contact_numbers.txt
```

**Approach 2:**

```
sed 's| *\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\).*|s/\1/\2/g|' <encrypted_contact_numbers.txt |
sed -f- students.txt > outfile.txt
```

Is there any way to process this huge file quickly?

**Update: 9-Feb-2018** 
 
Solutions given in AWK and Perl is working fine if the phone number is in specified position (column 10-20), If I try to do global replacement it took too much time to process. Is there any best way to achieve this?

**students.txt : Updated version**

> 1000000001**9234567890**XXX...**9234567890** 
>   1000000002**9325788532**YYY... 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   1001000000**8766443367**ZZZZ**9234567890**...

Comment: Edit the question to include the sed script.

Comment: In addition to what John mentioned please  add your encrypted_contact_numbers.txt too in code tags.

Comment: For correct formatting, please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as `code/data/output/errorMsgs`. For more info see  [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  sub(/ +$/,"");
  a[$1]=$2;
  next
}
(substr($0,11,10) in a){
  print substr($0,1,10) a[substr($0,11,10)] substr($0,21)
}
' FS=", " encrypted_contact_number.txt students.txt
```

Output will be as follows. Will add explanation too shortly.

```
10000000011122334455XXX...
10000000024466742178YYY...
```

Comment: This is working fine for sample. Cold you please explain the code so that  it will be implement into my actual scenario with huge file. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I was able to understand and tried to implemented the same in actual scenario. Its working fine, Thanks for your timely help!

Comment: Hi Ravinder. Is it possible to replace all matching number with encrypted number without mentioning position? like replace all

Comment: @Dhanabalan, please show example of it, not clear. If it is a new question then post it in a new thread too.

Comment: Initially I told 1st 10 characters are student ID and next 10 characters are contact number. So we used substr($0,11,10) to do replacement. Now I getting the file which has contact number in other positions also, so I trying to do replace all globally instead of particular position.

Comment: @Dhanabalan, why don't you post a new thread for it as answers were given in this thread are as per your 1st question, changing questions later will not be good as many users try to help you. Better choose a right answer(out of any answers feasible in here) and open a new post, thanks.

Comment: Sure. I have created another post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719330/sed-or-awk-replace-all-with-patterns-from-another-file

Thanks!

Comment: @Dhanabalan, choose a correct answer too, out of any. To reward people's effort. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I unknowingly removed it. Marked again

Answer (score 5):

`awk` to the rescue!

if you have enough memory to keep the phone_map file in memory

```
awk -F', *' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}
                    {key=substr($0,11,20)}
           key in a {$0=substr($0,1,10) a[key] substr($0,21)}1' phone_map data_file
```

not tested since you're missing the data file.  It should speed up since both files will be scanned only once.

Comment: I have added the sample data file  **(Students.txt)**

Comment: @Dhanabalan, please try to attach all details in a single shot to your post, try Karakfa and mine code and let us know how it goes then.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Won't the `next` in the first action block trigger on every line?  If so the other two blocks would never run.  Should it be `NF>1 {a[$1]=$2]; next}`?  Also, I think the `1` after the third action block is misplaced.

Comment: you're right of course. "first file" condition was missing, now added.  I typed directly here without testing first.

Comment: That `NR==FNR` is a nice trick I haven't seen before - thanks!  (For future readers, it is true if and only if the line you are on comes from the first file on the command line.)

Answer (score 2):

What question would be complete without a Perl answer? :)  Adapted from various answers in the [Perl Monks' discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=989705) of this topic.

#### Edited source

Edited per @Borodin's comment.  With some inline comments for explanation, in hopes that they are helpful.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;     # keep out of trouble
use warnings;   # ditto

my %numbers;    # map from real phone number to encrypted phone number

open(my $enc, '<', 'encrypted_contact_numbers.txt') or die("Can't open map file");
while(<$enc>) {
    s{\s+}{}g;                               #remove all whitespace
    my ($regular, $encrypted) = split ',';
    $numbers{$regular} = $encrypted;
}

# Make a regex that will match any of the numbers of interest
my $number_pattern = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %numbers;
$number_pattern = qr{$number_pattern}o;
    # Compile the regex - we no longer need the string representation

while(<>) {     # process each line of the input
    next unless length > 1;     # Skip empty lines (don't need this line if there aren't any in your input file)
    substr($_, 10, 10) =~ s{($number_pattern)}{$numbers{$1}}e;
    # substr: replace only in columns 11--20
    # Replacement (s{}{}e): the 'e' means the replacement text is perl code.
    print;  # output the modified line
}
```

#### Test

Tested on Perl v5.22.4.

**`encrypted_contact_numbers.txt`**:

```
9234567890, 1122334455
9325788532, 4466742178
```

**`students.txt`**:

```
aaaaaaaaaa9234567890XXX...
bbbbbbbbbb9325788532YYY...
cccccccccc8766443367ZZZZ...
dddddddddd5432112345Nonexistent phone number
```

(modified for ease of reading)

**Output** of `./process.pl students.txt`:

```
aaaaaaaaaa1122334455XXX...
bbbbbbbbbb4466742178YYY...
cccccccccc8766443367ZZZZ...
dddddddddd5432112345Nonexistent phone number
```

The change has been made on the first two lines, but not the second two, which is correct for this input.

Comment: It diminishes our efforts to encourage best practices when you publish an *answer* without `use strict` or `use warnings`, using the two-parameter `open`, no information in the `die` string, and global file handles. In addition -- Why are you using `quotemeta` on strings of digits? -- Your `$numbers{$1} || $1` is pointless—you just built the regex pattern out of the hash keys. You're also holding on to a hash of over a million records long after you've finished using it to build a regex.

Comment: @Borodin because I'm still learning, and trying to give back while doing so. 
 Thanks for the feedback!  **quotemeta** because I don't want to assume the OP's file is only digits.  I agree it should be, but better safe than sorry.  **`|| $1`** if I leave this out, I get `Use of uninitialized value within %numbers in substitution iterator` on lines that match.  Why?

Comment: @Borodin I can no longer repro the problem I was having - not sure what the deal was.  Anyway, fixed version is above.  I do need to keep the hash for the replacement values in the main loop, but don't need to keep the `join` result, so I changed that.

Comment: *"It's much shorter without the comments!"* You should leave them out. It's not your place to teach people Perl in every program you write. *"if I leave this out, I get `Use of uninitialized value within %numbers in substitution iterator`"* I can't get that behaviour. // Also, you shouldn't have the `/g` modifier on the substitution, and you have no reason to avoid the standard slash delimiters for `s///` and `m//`.

Comment: @Borodin Yep, I got rid of the `/g` modifier.  `s{}{}` is only because, in my browser, the syntax highlighter can't properly parse `s///`.  Re. comments, the OP specifically asked another answerer "Co[u]ld you please explain the code".  Whether or not it's my place, I think it's not unreasonable to comment in anticipation of a similar request.

Comment: As for explaining the code, I always write a separate narrative before the code itself. And the familiarity of the `s///` delimiters is more important than the highlighting. It's usually because it's expecting an even number of slashes and you can fix it by adding a comment `#/`. Note that you can write `s/($number_pattern)/{ $numbers{$1} }e` which you may prefer as it emphasizes that the replacement is Perl code.

Comment: Remember that you can post your code on [*Code Review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get this sort of assessment.

Comment: Thanks everyone, This is the first time I am trying Perl.